# JMenuItem linked to another window from a different class

Tags: java

so i have a class for a window with JMenuItems and it suppose to open new windows when it clicked
but the windows are from other classes so i had to make an object for them and it worked when i let only one JMenuItem perform an action but when i added more it showed that is not correct
help me fix this
here is the JMenuItems:

```
JMenuItem managestudent = new JMenuItem ("manage student");
  menu.add(managestudent);
  JMenuItem mangecourse = new JMenuItem ("manage course");
  menu.add(mangecourse);
```

and here is the way i made it perform but it did't

```
 class exitaction implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
  System.exit(0);
  exit.addActionListener(new exitaction ());
  }
  
  
  
  class open implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     ManageStudent n= new ManageStudent();
  managestudent.addActionListener(new open());
  }
  
   class open2 implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     ManageCourse m = new ManageCourse();
     mangecourse.addActionListener(new open2());
   }
```

ManageStudent and mangecourse  are from different classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the menu item to call your `ActionListener`s when it is clicked, you must add the `ActionListener` to the menu item. You don't appear to do this, consequently the `ActionListener`s are never called.

Here's the correct code. First add the action listeners to the menu item:

```
JMenuItem managestudent = new JMenuItem ("manage student");
  menu.add(managestudent);
  managestudent.addActionListener(new open());
  JMenuItem mangecourse = new JMenuItem ("manage course");
  menu.add(mangecourse);
  mangecourse.addActionListener(new open2());
```

Then, in your `ActionListener` objects, change the code as follows:

```
class exitaction implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
  // code to execute when exit menu item is clicked
  System.exit(0);
  }
  
  
  
  class open implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     // code to execute when manage student menu item is clicked
     ManageStudent n= new ManageStudent();
  }
  
   class open2 implements ActionListener{
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
     // code to execute when manage course menu item is clicked
     ManageCourse m = new ManageCourse();
   }
```